# PHP - array_diff() missing a record

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays:

$indexedProducts =

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6662
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6656
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6657
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6527
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6528
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6529
    )
```

and
$categoryProducts =

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6527
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6528
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6529
    )
```

i am then running this command:

```
$difference = array_diff($indexedProducts[0], $categoryProducts[0]);
```

**the result i am expecting** from this is an array of the values 6662,6656 and 6657:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6662
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6656
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6657
    )
```

as these all occur in the first array and not in the second array.

**The result i am receiving** from this is

```
[id] => 6662
```

it seems to be stopping at the first index not found.

**Where am i going wrong with this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually need to diff on is the ID column in both multi arrays:

```
array_diff(
    array_column($indexedProducts, 'id'),
    array_column($categoryProducts, 'id')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array_diff only works on flat arrays.

Use array_column to make the arrays flat before diff-ing them.

```
var_dump(array_diff(array_column($indexedProducts, "id"), array_column($categoryProducts, "id")));
//[6662,6656,6657]
```

https://3v4l.org/5fsLE